# Storing multi-dimensional data in Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

First off, I'm still a relative newbie to the world of React & Redux. I'm reading about [Normalizing State Shape](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/NormalizingStateShape.html), and their examples are about storing data by ID. But what if I have data that is keyed on multiple dimensions?

For example, my app is displaying cost data for a given Service ID, which is retrieved from an API. However, the user is able to select a time range. The start and end timestamps are passed to the API, and the API returns the aggregated data over that time range. I want to be able to store all the different time period data in Redux so if the user goes back to a previous time period, that data is already there (our API is slow, so having already loaded data available is critical to user experience).

So not only do I have data keyed by Service ID, but also by Start Time / End Time. Since Redux recommends flat data structures, I wonder how flat should I make it? Because normally, I would store the data like this:

```
{
  costData: {
    [service_id]: {
      [start_time]: {
        [end_time]: {
          /* data */
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But that seems to go about the idea of flattening the data. One of my ideas was to generate an ID based on Service ID & Start Time & End Time of the form:

```
<ServiceID>::<StartTime>::<EndTime>
```

eg.

```
00123::1505423419::1505785502
```

So the data is fairly flat:

```
{
  costData: {
    '00123::1505423419::1505785502': {
      /* data */
    }
  }
}
```

The component can generate this ID and pass it to the `fetchCostData()` action, which can dispatch and fetch the data and store that data on that generated ID. But I don't know if that's the best approach. Are there any guidelines or recommendations on how to approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using selectors (Reselect) for this nested data, if you're not comfortable with modifying your api.

-> Selectors are the best approach for computing derived data, allowing Redux to store the minimal possible state.

-> Selectors are efficient. A selector is not recomputed unless one of its arguments change.

-> Selectors are composable. They can be used as input to other selectors.

Comment: So if I understand the use of selectors properly, I could store my data nested as I have in my original post, and then create a selector -- `getCurrentCosts(id, timeStart, timeEnd)`, which will create a derived state that will only get recomputed only if I give different inputs.

Comment: yes exactly, it recalculates when there is state change. Selectors are best way to calculate and do manipulations without disturbing the redux state.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answer, you may want to read the article [Advanced Redux Entity Normalization](https://medium.com/@dcousineau/advanced-redux-entity-normalization-f5f1fe2aefc5), which describes ways to track additional lookup descriptions of normalized data.  I also have some other articles on normalization in the [Redux Techniques#Selectors and Normalization](https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links/blob/master/redux-techniques.md#selectors-and-normalization) section of my [React/Redux links list](https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links/blob/master/redux-techniques.md).